# If statement is working whereas Else statement does not work

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

```
<?php
  // Check connection

     $servername = "localhost";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "1234";
     $dbname = "project";

     htmlspecialchars($a = $row1['stno']);

     $d1 = $row7['userID'];

       // Create connection
               $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
       // Check connection
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM likes WHERE rec = $a";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);

                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                         $z4 = $row['do'];
                         if ($d1 == $z4)
                         {
                             include ("unlikee.php");
                         }
                         else {
                             include ("likee.php");
                         }
                    }
                } 
                $conn->close();
       ?>
```

This is a like button connected with my sql all is working fine , but the problem is with Else statement

```
            else 
        include ("likee.php");
```

it's not working whereas if statement works out. The Logic is unlikee.php contains the script to unlike where likee.php contains vice versa , and whenever their is a like already placed , the unlike button is shown but whenever their is no like , the Like button is invisible

Comment: try var:dump($d1); var:dump($z4) and check for the real content ..

Comment: Also consider looking into properly indenting your PHP code (see [this](http://beta.phpformatter.com/)) to increase readability of your code. It's hard to follow as it stands.

Comment: If I understood it right, when there is no Like from that user your script shows nothing? If the problem were the conditional then it would always show an unlike button. If it shows nothing then it is actually moving into the else section (otherwise it would show the unlike button) and the problem may be in the likee.php file.

Comment: @Marc there is no problem in the likee.php  because i tested it outside loop and it works but it does not work inside loop

Comment: @CounterAim That may be, but if the main script wouldn't move into the else section then it would print the unlike button. Either it doesn't move into the else and the unlikee.php file fails in some cases or it does move into the else section and the likee.php fails always (when inside the loop). First determine whether it moves into else or not (remove the includes and just do echo("if") echo("else")) to check if the conditional works. If it does then check why likee.php fails when inside the loop.

Comment: I did what you said @Marc Compte i added

 else 
     
   **   echo ("hello"); **
   


but it still does not go to else

Comment: I don't see any error in the code you provided. If it doesn't move ever into the else bit and you don't see any error in the logs, then it may be that $d1 is always equal to $z4 (check it, print both values on each iteration of the loop).

Answer (score 0):

You said "whenever there is no like, the like button is invisible". That's because you never execute the part of the code that includes the like or unlike buttons when there are no likes

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
```

Updated code segment. When the number of result rows is 0 then the else is executed to include likee.php

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $z4 = $row['do'];
    if ($d1 == $z4) {
          include ("unlikee.php");
    } 
} else {
    include ("likee.php");
}
```

Comment: i did @john , I don't know what's the trouble , can you please correct it for me please ?